# Команда, префикс и режим адресации

Tags: ассемблер, машинный-код

Как указать поле префикса команды, поле самой команды, поле режим адрессации?

Comment: @Иван1009, уточните вопрос, какой именно префикс нужен, какая команда, какой режим адресации?

Answer (score 2):

Машинная команда в общем случае выглядит так: сначала идут префиксы, каждый префикс занимает 1 байт, далее идет поле команды - как правило занимает 1-2 байта, дальше для указания режима адресации может идти байт mod r/m, далее в зависимости от значений полей байта mod r/m может идти байт sib (scale-index-base), далее может идти численное смещение или непосредственный операнд.

По этой теме можно почитать следующее:

- ["Тонкости Дизассемблирования (дизассемблирование в уме)" Криса Касперски (pdf)](http://kpnc.opennet.ru/DISASS.PDF)
- Книга Пирогов В. "Ассемблер и дизассемблирование" глава "Формат команд микропроцессора Intel"
- Для более полной информации нужно читать мануалы интела.